# Sitemap is not generated showing error magento 2.2.5

Tags: magento2

I am getting this message when trying to generate site map from backend magento.

Path "/sitemap" is not available and cannot be used.

I have also changed the path to pub/media/ but getting same result.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

you might create a sitemap folder at the root of your site and make sure this folder has write permissions by your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

Change the name of the sitemap to sitemap.xml. It should fix your issue.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to know that it works. Please, choose it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Magento automatically prepends the given path with `/pub/media`. So the new folder you need to create needs to be situated within `pub/media/` of your Magento instance. For example, if you configure the path to be `/sitemaps/`, then the folder you need to create beforehand is `pub/media/sitemaps/`.

Magento's [user manual](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/sitemap-xml.html) does not mention this at all though. It says the following:

> `/` » Places the site map file at the base path, or root of your Commerce installation.

But looking at the code itself, Magento seems to automatically determine `pub/media` as the writable location when executing

```php
$filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::PUB)
```

At least in Magento `2.4.3`.